# Get a new token with the refresh token symfony oauth2

Tags: php, symfony, oauth-2.0, fosuserbundle, fosrestbundle

I work on symfony project with [FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle), [FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle) and [FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle).

In the security part, I can't get my new access token with using the refresh token. I can only get my access token. I have followed some tutorials and I got this error when I try to get a new token:

```
{
   "error": "unauthorized_client",
   "error_description": "Le type de subvention est non autorisee pour cette client_id"
}
```

The url is: http://myproject.local/oauth/v2/token

The params are :

> - grant_type: refresh_token
> - client_id: client_id
> - client_secret: client_secret
> - refresh_token: refresh_token

Did I missed any configuration? Or the I used a wrong url or a wrong params?
Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates that your client is not allowed to use the `refresh_token` grant type.
What you have to do is to add this grant type to your client (code not tested):

```
$clientManager = $this->container->get('fos_oauth_server.client_manager.default'); // Get the Client manager
$client = $clientManager->findClientByPublicId('PUBLIC ID OF YOUR CLIENT HERE'); // Get the Client
$grant = $client->getAllowedGrantTypes(); // Get the grant types
$grant[] = 'refresh_token'; // Add the refresh_token grant type
$client->setAllowedGrantTypes($grant); // Modify your Client
$clientManager->updateClient($client); // Save your Client
```